# TexShop Autocompletes & with a period

Tags: texshop, auto-completion, macos

For some reason, TexShop started autocompleting any ampersand & by adding a period/full stop, which is not a feature that I consider desirable, given that I almost exclusively use the symbol for tabular and align environments. I feel that there is probably a simple way to turn this behavior off in the preferences, but I couldn't see how to do so. How do I change the default behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! The default command completion file contains no completion for `&` (or `\&`) at all. Are you sure this is being done by command completion and not the MacOS keyboard preferences autocorrect list?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks that was it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of Alan Munn solved the problem; it was a MacOS autocomplete issue, now resolved. ("add period after double space")